# Decide when product of discrete topologies is discrete itself

Tags: general-topology

> $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$  be discrete topological spaces and $X=\prod_{i\in\Lambda} X_i.$ Then which of the following statements imply that the product topology on $X$ equals the discrete topology on $X\ ?$
>
> $1.\Lambda \text{ is finite}.$
>
> $2.\Lambda \text{ is countably infinite and }X_{i} \text{ are singletons for all but a finite number of } i's.$
>
> $3.\Lambda \text{ is uncountably infinite and }X_{i} \text{ are singletons for all but a finite number of } i.$
>
> $4.\Lambda \text{ is infinite and }X_i \text{ are infinite for all  }\  i.$

**For case $1$**, product and discrete topology on $X$ are same.

**For case $2$**, let the ones that are not singletons be names $X_1,X_2,............X_n,$  and the rest are $\{x_{n_1}\},\{x_{n+2}\}...............$  and so on. Here too both the topologies are same follows from the definition of product topology.

**For case $3$,** since only finitely many of the $X_i$'s have more than one element, product and box topology are same on this too.

Now **case $4$**  is confusing me a little but I think this will  have both the topologies same since **arbitrary  union**  of open sets is open.

Am I correct ? Please correct me if there is any mistake and help find the right answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that a basis for $\prod_{i\in\Lambda}X_i$ is given by the sets $\prod_{i\in\Lambda}U_i$ where $U_i\subseteq X_i$ are open and all but finitely many are the whole of $X_i$. It is easy to see that this implies that for each open set $U\subseteq\prod_{i\in\Lambda}X_i$ we have that $\pi_i(U) = X_i$ for infinitely many $i\in\Lambda$, where $\pi_i$ is the projection onto $X_i$ (to see this, notice that this is true for the elements of the basis and remains true when taking arbitrary unions and finite intersections). Therefore, the topology on $\prod_{i\in\Lambda}X_i$ cannot be discrete in case **(4)**.

As remarked by @BrianM.Scott in the comments, this in fact shows that if infinitely many $X_i$ have strictly more than one element, then $\prod_{i\in\Lambda}X_i$ cannot have the dicrete topology.

You found the correct answer for the other three cases.

Comment: Great!  +1 from me.

Comment: You might go on to point out that in fact all that’s needed for this argument to work is for infinitely many of the $X_i$ to have more than one element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Done. Thanks for the remark.